# Show that $\mu(E \cup A) + \mu(E \cap A) = \mu(E) + \mu(A)$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $X$, then show that for every subset $A$ of $X$ the following equality holds: $$\mu(E \cup A) + \mu(E \cap A) = \mu(E) + \mu(A).$$

I know since $E$ is measurable $$\mu(A) = \mu(A\cap E) + \mu(A \cap(X\setminus E))$$ for every subset $A$ of $X$.

I am not sure how to continue with this? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: This is a good start. Hint: $E\cup A$ is the disjoint union of $A\cap(X\setminus E)$, $E\cap(X\setminus A)$, and $A\cap E$.

Answer (score 1):

Combining your own observation and the hint by @GregMartin, we get
$$\mu(E\cap(X \setminus A)) + \mu(A) = \mu(E \cup A).$$
Now observe that $\mu(E\cap(X \setminus A)) = \mu(E \cap A^c) = \mu(E) - \mu(E \cap A)$, so
$$\mu(E) - \mu(E\cap A) + \mu(A) = \mu(E \cup A),$$
which is what we wanted.